# QGIS. Edited vertices revert back to original position when saving layer edits

Tags: qgis, editing

But when I hover over where the new line was before saving, the edits appear in red. If I right click the mouse, that line disappears and red circles appear on the original line. The feature class is a line. This is a new problem on a project that has been working fine before now. In this same session, a new line feature disappears after digitizing when I hit the Save Layer Edits.

Comment: Where ist the Layer stored? Local or in a DB?
Did you try to reload the layer? Did you try to reload the project?

Comment: @fsg Hey thanks, I think that is the problem! The layer source is now showing as a pdf so it somehow changed when I exported it to pdf for a map. What is the proper way to reload the layer? The layer is stored locally.

Comment: I used R Click> Change Data Source and I think things are working! Thanks for your help.